# Is there an equivalent of 'HasQueryFilter' for MongoDb like EntityFramework has?

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework-core

For EntityFramework we apply some query filters to every request made to the database by using EF's `HasQueryFilter`.
This ensures that on a higher level we don't have to worry about extra filtering that is being added and we can't forget to do that.

I was wondering if something like that also exists for MongoDb or if I have to write my own wrapper?

Comment: no such feature exists for the official mongodb c# driver. if you don't mind using a wrapper library, **mongodb.entities** can [add global filters](https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/5d8ddc96ed4a5f5d5d1ad937e089b15b) by overriding the `DBContext` base class. disclaimer: i'm the author of the library.